# Call signalr from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a ChatHub sending message to the client:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

How can I call the Send function to broadcast the message to all client from `another controller`?

I have tried this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(Chat chat)
{
    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
    hubContext.Clients.All.Send(chat.Name, chat.Message);
}
```

Comment: That should work. Have you set a breakpoint to see if it is being called?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to call `addNewMessageToPage` in your `Post` action method.

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(chat.Name, chat.Message);
```

Then in your JS file:

```
var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;

chatHub.client.addNewMessageToPage= function (name, message) {
    //Add name and message to the page here
};
$.connection.hub.start();
```